# How to get pulse sound level?

Tags: shell-script, pulseaudio

I am using simple keyboard shortcuts to adjust the sound level on my `fluxbox`

```
123 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 5+
122 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 5-
```

However I would like to add some notification (notify-send) of actual sound level.

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: With a Pulse Audio device, I use the following command to check the current volume: "amixer -D pulse get Master"  Maybe you can use the output of that command to create your notification message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with this command:

```
notify-send "$(amixer -D pulse get Master | awk '$2== "Left:" {print $5}')"
```

Comment: however there is a little problem with notification (notify-send). It has very long expiration time